# 'require' not working with rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm

The following code lives inside my rails app's root folder and daemonizes/runs `myserver.rb`.

```
# myserver_control.rb

require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'    # causes 'no such file to load -- daemons' error since gem reinstall with rvm

@options = {
    # options defined
}

Daemons.run('myserver.rb', @options)
```

It was working just fine until I installed rvm and now it can't seem to find the daemons gem. I have a feeling maybe the above is searching for the daemons gem in a system wide folder somewhere? Instead of being able to use the rvm installed daemons gem? How do I install the daemons gem on a system level where it can find it? OR how do I make it so it can find the rvm installed gem?

Currently I do not even have a 'system' gem set. How would I install gems on the system level after having already installed rvm?

Comment: How are you executing `myserver.rb`?

Comment: I run `sudo ruby myserver_control.rb start` from the command line. It's a command provided by the daemons ruby gem.

Comment: As @Egryan said, sudo and rvm don't mix. This was a gotcha for me too when I first started using RVM, e.g.: http://blog.gomiso.com/2012/09/11/hello-new-friends-hello-old-friend/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If wishing to use the system ruby and gems you can type in

```
rvm use system
```

which will allow to use the system installed ruby and gems, but I think this kinda of defeats the purpose of using RVM  I would instead install a default ruby in RVM and install any gems into that. To set a default Ruby after you have installed it, type this

```
rvm --default use 1.9.2
```

**Edit**

Based on comment your problem lies with running sudo, this creates a new subshell and different instance of rvm

Comment: My rails app in general is using the rvm installed gems. But the daemons control code above seems to be displaying its own behavior--looking for the system gems instead of using the rvm installed gems. So I am trying to figure out how to make it either (1)Find the rvm installed daemons gem--which it cannot find OR (2)Install the daemons gem on the system level--considering that I already have rvm installed. Any advice on either of these two solutions would be great.

Comment: well if you do rvm use system it will revert to system installed ruby and gems which you can then install daemons gem.  Quick question are you reinstalling the gem after you install and setup rvm.  ie but the dameons gem in your gemfile and run bundle update

Comment: Yes. I definitely have all of my required gems in my Gemfile and ran bundle update and all gems are installed in the expected folder. It is just my ruby scripts here that seem to be looking in the wrong place (system gem folder) for my gems.

Comment: I noticed that in the commands above you are running sudo ruby myserver control.rb start, you should not be running sudo and I am sure that is where you problem lies.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation in the edit of what sudo actually does here.

Answer (score 0):

RVM uses a concept of gemsets, which are unique groups of gems that you can use, most often specific to ruby versions (although you can make them specific to applications or global).

RVM will change your GEM_HOME when changing ruby versions, which tells ru ygems where your gems are installed. So when you installed RVM, you created a new blank gemset and RVM told rubygems to use that.

This is because gems are not always cross compatible between rubygems.

However, if you just writing rails apps, you should ignore the above for now and use bundler. Place 'gem "daemon"' I am your Gemfile and run bundle update from your app root directory.

Bundle helps you maintain gems on a per app basis, which means your app won't break if you upgrade a gem somewhere else. Using it and knowing how it works is best practices. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, this is how I have installed everything and my rails app itself can certainly find all the gems. It's the server scripts that do little jobs for my app (like the one above) that can't seem to find my app's gems. Can I provide a full path to the rvm installed gem somehow?